# Magento Product Images Not Resizing

Tags: php, css, magento, magento-1.6

I uninstalled an extension and afterwards all of my product images displayed on category pages resized to **135x135** instead of **209x209**. I checked the `list.phtml` and this is what I found:

```
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this-   >stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(209); ?>" width="209" height="209" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
```

Although this looks right to me I am also find a random css attribute that appears to be the culprit I just cannot find any source of the rule.

```
img[Attributes Style] {
width: 135px;
height: 135px;
}
```

You can see my problem [here](http://www.nitrousoutlet.com/efi-wet-nitrous-systems.html)

Comment: what extension did you used and uninstalled

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right `list.phtml` file? It's likely that an extension overwrote it, as the images on your site have clearly been resized to 135x135 (you can see `135x` in the file path) and have a `width` and `height` attribute of 135.

Comment: @VIVEK-MDU I uninstalled "Delete Orders" [See it here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/delete-order-3590.html)

Comment: @giaour From everything that I have been able to find list.phtml should be right, but I did check most of the other phtml files and could't find anything that would cause it to resize to 135. I also see it the file path I just dont know where its getting 135px from.

Comment: If you have any extensions affecting the product list pages, check to see if they have anything in the layout xml file that looks like this: `<action method="setTemplate"><template>XXX.phtml</template></action>`

Comment: @giaour thank you! I guess when I uninstalled that extension it reset my product view template to some other random template. I appreciate everyone's help!

Comment: @thadw cool! I put my last comment up as answer since it helped you track down the bug.

Answer (score 0):

An extension is overwriting the template for the product list, so the file you modified (`list.phtml`) isn't actually what's showing.

If you have any extensions affecting the product list pages, check to see if they have anything in the layout xml file that looks like this: `<action method="setTemplate"><template>XXX.phtml</template></action>`.

Answer (score 0):

this is lazy trick..use a software has feature search text in file, then try search with search keyword "resize(135"